# env.render() not implemented after using gym.vector.SyncVectorEnv

Tags: python, numpy, video, record, openai-gym

I am working with the gym library and want to save a recording of the episodes. I tried using `from gym.wrappers.monitoring.video_recorder import VideoRecorder` and  `gym.wrappers.RecordVideo` and both result in `raise NotImplemented` of the env.render() function. I create the environment like this

```
def make_env():
    # env = gym.make('CarRacing-v2', render_mode="human")
    env = gym.make('CarRacing-v2', render_mode='rgb_array')
    env = normalize_obs(env) # gym.ObservationWrapper
    env = BoundAction(env, low=0, high=1) # gym.ActionWrapper
    return env

single_env = make_env()
env = gym.vector.SyncVectorEnv([lambda: single_env])

env = gym.wrappers.RecordVideo(env, "recording")
```

I can do single_env.render() but i cannot do env.render(). Can I somehow record a video even with a gym.vector.SyncVectorEnv environment?

If I put single_env into RecordVideo then my code crashes because it gets a different dimension than it should have gotten.

Is there a function where I can just manually add the rendered images from single_env instead of a whole wrapper?